# Asking for Video Editing, Workflow advice between VSE & Compositing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, workflow, compositing-nodes

I am struggling with strips & VSE because I found no way to apply a node on a strip.
The purpose is to make an old moving processing. The Raw video is in FullHD.
I believe the several steps of editing & processing should be in this order

1. Lens distorsion & Crop into a TV Ratio
2. Motion Design (Text, Images....)
3. Color Grading (desaturation, levels, sepia color cast)
4. Scratches on film (come from another video)
5. Vignette for old film framing
6. Projector shake (transform node?)

**What I found out for each step:**

1/ Is there a way to do this without a Lens Distorsion Node (ie in the VSE?)

2/ Can only be done in the VSE

3/ Could be done in the VSE (with pain), can be done with nodes

4/ Can either be done in compositing with a mix node or in the VSE with a lighten blend

5/ Can either be done in compositing or VSE

6/ Can be done with a Transform node or on a big meta strip which is a solution I don't like.

**If I summarize:**
**FIRST** compositing of all raw videos
**SECOND** MOTION DESIGN over the processed videos
**THIRD** Compositing round 2 to make the final rendering
(Audio is another matter).

Do you have comments, advices about this statement of work ?
Thanks ;)

Comment: at first glance that sounds about right, but I would add that considering how slow blender is at rendering video passes compared to dedicated video editing software, it might be worth considering using something else? I think you'd be able to do all of that in one go with a program like flowblade

Comment: Well I don't plan on spending dozens of hours to learn a new tool. If things cannot be optimized with Blender then so be it.
For VSE videos, I use a script made by Mickeycal Meyers to dispatch the work on several cores/threads. I works well.

Comment: yep, totally understand what you mean, t'was just a suggestion. and yep, the multi-threading script is very useful stuff.

Comment: actually, you can combine step 1 and 2 by having the raw video composited in its own scene, then import it into the VSE of a different scene. That way you could skip the first render, but using this technique massively slows down blender preview

Comment: Why struggle and suffer with the VSE when there are so many better tools that will allow you to do this? Blender is so rudimentary, inefficient and haphazardly designed for serious video work. Use any other contemporary video editing app, one that will allow you to do all of this directly on the timeline without multigenerations, proxies, conversions and the time wasting workflows or workarounds in blender.

Comment: I don't pretend doing serious video work ;)
Yet if you have suggestions of other video editors which are completly relevant for this kind of work, I am reading to listen to them.